# using parseFloat to apply on a specific td class

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there something wrong with the code below
Just trying to fix decimal paces for a specific class of td.
need to use only jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <td class="go"> 25.252525
    </td>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
      $('.go').each(function() {
       return parseFloat($(this).toFixed(2));       
    }
    
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `.text()` to get text from td then use `.toFixed()` and finally change updated value inside your `td` i.e : `$(this).text(parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2));`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.go').each(function() {
  $(this).text(parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2)); //change text..
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="go"> 25.252525
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="go"> 25.2223525
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```